# Django form geocoding - where to geocode, how to validate, how to pass geocode result

Tags: django, forms, validation, geocode

I have a very simple Django form which consists of a single field - "address":

```
class AddressSearchForm(forms.Form):
    """
        A form that allows a user to enter an address to be geocoded
    """
    address = forms.CharField()
```

I probably do not even need to use a form, since I'm not saving this data - I'm just collecting it to use in a search. But, I want to perform validation:

```
def clean_address():
    data = self.cleaned_data
    g = geocoders.Google()
    try:
        place, (lat,lng) = g.geocode(data['address'])
    except (GQueryError):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a valid address')
    except (GeocoderResultError, GBadKeyError, GTooManyQueriesError):
        raise forms.ValidationError('There was an error geocoding your address. Please      try again')
    except:
        raise forms.ValidationError('An unknown error occured. Please try again')
```

In addition, I want to use this geocoded result to pass a Point object to my view:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
point = Point(lng, lat)
```

My question is, how to pass both the address and the point data to my view? I could just pass the address and then re-geocode in the view, but that would be duplicating code. So, how to pass the point object from the form? Should I use a hidden field? Other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no django expert, but this is what I did:

```
 def clean_homeaddress(self):
        in_address = self.cleaned_data['homeaddress']        
        place, self.cleaned_data['homelocation'] = address_to_latlng(in_address, True)
        return place
```

oh, and by the way, have a look at the wrapper below. geocoders.Google doesn't handle unicode strings properly. There's a simple hack below which removes all non-ascii characters. I haven't had time to figure out better solution yet.

```
def address_to_latlng(address, return_address = False):
    """ returns GoeDjango POINT string value for given location (address)
        if return_address is true, it'll return 2-tuple: (address, point)
        otherwise it returns point
    """ 
    g = geocoders.Google()
    try:
        #TODO: not really replace, geocode should use unicode strings
        address = address.encode('ascii', 'replace')            
        place, latlng = g.geocode(address)            
    except Exception as e:            
        raise ValidationError(_(u"Incorrect location provided"))
    point = 'POINT(%f %f)' % tuple(reversed(latlng))
    if return_address:
        return (place, point)    
    return point
```

---

as requested, there's full code. this one will print the location to the output console, and it'll keep the "cleaned" (as returned by Google) address in the session, to display it to the user each time the form is displayed.

```
class GeoForm(forms.Form):
    address = forms.CharField()    

    def clean_address(self):
        in_address = self.cleaned_data['address']        
        place, self.cleaned_data['location'] = address_to_latlng(in_address, True)
        return place

class GeoView(FormView):
    form_class = GeoForm
    template_name = 'geoview.html'
    success_url = '/sandbox/geo'
    def get_initial(self):
        if '_address' in self.request.session:
            return {'address': self.request.session['_address']}
        return {}
    def form_valid(self,form):
        print form.cleaned_data['location']
        self.request.session['_address'] = form.cleaned_data['address']
        return super(GeoView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: thanks. what does your form look like? How are you passing both homeaddress and homelocation?

Comment: Also, how are you accessing this data in your view?

Comment: And, for a Django Point string, shouldn't longitude go first?

Comment: the form contains only homeaddress charfield, as I have no reason to show the user POINT data (homelocation value). I'm accessing it in the view using form.cleaned_data['homelocation'] ...
Considering Point, you are absolutely right. This was fixed later, I just opened the wrong file copy.

Comment: Are you using class-based views? Are you using the location data to do a query? would you mind sharing your view code? I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how the form and view interact in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: @DouglasMeehan there you go :)